# Embedded python not picking up PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, c, winapi, python-stackless

I have a really weird problem with embedding python. If I don't specify `PYTHONPATH`, `Py_Initialize` fails with `ImportError: No module named site`.

If I set `PYTHONPATH` in cmd and then run my program, it works!

If I set `PYTHONPATH` programmatically (`_putenv_s` / `SetEnvironmentVariable`) it fails with `ImportError` again.

I've checked that the value is set with `system("echo %PYTHONPATH%");`, I've made sure multiple times that it is the correct path. I have no idea why it's failing... any ideas appreciated.

Setup: win10 x64, stackless python 2.7 x86 embedded in a C program.

Comment: I'm going to place my bet on failure to account for file system redirection. Without seeing any code, information on the execution environment, nor even the input to `_putenv_s`, this remains to be a guessing game. You'll need to improve your question to receive better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to set `PYTHONPATH` before, then load the dll with a delay. The python library I have seems to be non-standard / modified.

Comment: I have tried but not work. my version is Python 3.7.0rc1 (v3.7.0rc1:dfad352267, Jun 12 2018, 06:15:26) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. Beside, I print sys.path cannot find the PYTHONPATH content.

Answer (score 4):

https://bugs.python.org/issue28245

I found that python37._pth could be used to configure the sys.path info.

```
python37.zip
.
Lib
Lib\site-packages

# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```