# pip with embedded python

Tags: python, pip

I installed embedded python from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/), titled "Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file", but it does not have pip installed, it does not have site-packages either, when I try to do `python get-pip.py` it failed to run because this file has `import pip` in it. So how can I install pip within a embedded python environment.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File ".\getpip.py", line 20061, in 
>     main()
>     File ".\getpip.py", line 194, in main
>       bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
>     File ".\getpip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
>       import pip
>     File "", line 961, in _find_and_load
>     File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>     File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked
>     File "", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible

The directory structure is:

```
Directory: C:\Downloads\python-3.6.1rc1-embed-win32

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM         157344 pyexpat.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          97952 python.exe
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          58016 python3.dll
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM        3263648 python36.dll
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM        2209284 python36.zip
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM             79 python36._pth
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          96416 pythonw.exe
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          23200 select.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM         866464 sqlite3.dll
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM         895648 unicodedata.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          83784 vcruntime140.dll
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          24224 winsound.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          45216 _asyncio.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          77984 _bz2.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM         101536 _ctypes.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM         215712 _decimal.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM         156832 _elementtree.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM        1042592 _hashlib.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM         183456 _lzma.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          32416 _msi.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          25760 _multiprocessing.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          33952 _overlapped.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          61600 _socket.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM          64160 _sqlite3.pyd
-a----         3/4/2017   7:26 PM        1458848 _ssl.pyd
```

Comment: get-pip is able to install pip even if pip isn't installed. Are you sure you're running in the conext of the embedded python? Can you show the "WHERE" that the python executable is running from?

Comment: @nir0s where do you mean where? I run it from the folder that was unzipped with the zip file.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Which folder? Can you print the directory contents of that folder?

Comment: @nir0s I have updated the post with the folder contents.

Comment: Related: [Adding packages to Python “embedded” installation for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737721/adding-packages-to-python-embedded-installation-for-windows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently ran into the same issue. I checked the documentation for pip and they seem to say that this use case isn't supported etc. But anyhow, here is my hack for getting the modules to work.

I installed, and by that I mean unzipped embedded python into a directory called d:\python. I assumed that the modules are going to live in that same directory.

First, to install the pip module, I needed to save the extraceted files. I changed the get-pip.py using a text editor that supported *unix* line terminators by removing the rmtree lines that remove the temporary and unpacked tree from the blob containted in the get-pip.py file.

I changed both locations, but only the last one was needed. The line that I changed in two locations read

```
shutil.rmtree(tmpdir, ignore_errors=True)
```

and I modified it thus (I didn't want to bother with the python indentation blocks):

```
print('shutil.rmtree(tmpdir, ignore_errors=True)')
```

I now ran my python D:\python\python.exe on the modified get-pip.py and found the temporary directory where the files were unzipped to.

I copied this directory, (check that it contains a **main**.py) file into the python install D:\python\pip (this is where I wanted my modules to live), ensuring that the D:\python\pip directory contained the **main**.py file.

The pip module is now installed in the python directory, but you need to hack pip further to remove the exception above. I did this by changing the locations.py file (in my case located in D:\python\pip\locations.py) to return the bin_py and bin_user locations of D:\python.

ie:

```
86 if WINDOWS:
....
bin_py = 'd:/python'
bin_user = 'd:/python'
```

I had to change the user_dir for pip to somewhere that would persist on this drive that was shared across multiple VMs.

The pip module now runs fine, eg

> d:\python\python.exe -m pip ...

Comment: this work fine, thanks, but if i install 3-d side packages it put it into d:\python\Lib\site-packages and don't see

Comment: You might want to check the site paths.

Comment: i cant find how to add into paths 'd:\python\Lib\site-packages' permanently otherwise it make me add this path every time i use my embedded python

Comment: Yon don't need to hardcode the location, use `bin_py = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` and `bin_user = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` instead.

Answer (score 89):

Even if explicitly stated that the embeddable [version of Python does not
support Pip](//docs.python.org/using/windows.html#windows-embeddable), it is possible with care. You need to:

1. Download and unzip Python [embeddable zip](//python.org/downloads) file.
2. In the file `python39._pth` or similar, uncomment the `import` command.
   Result should look similar to this:

   ```
   python39.zip
   .
   import site
   ```
3. [Download get-pip.py](//pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing) to the Python install folder
4. Run `get-pip.py`. this installs Pip into the `Scripts` directory:

   ```
   python get-pip.py
   ```
5. Run Pip directly from command line as Pip is a executable program (this
   example is to install Pandas):

   ```
   .\Scripts\pip install pandas
   ```

You could find more information about this in the [Pip issue 4207](//github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4207)

Comment: pip install fine but then won't run properly or at all. "_pth" file needs a touch: add ".\Lib\site-packages\" below "."

Comment: and I have just found out that deleting/renaming "_pth" file frees this installation from embedded. with "_pth" file python will not recognize any other environment variable, especially PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz Very late here... but did you come across any negative consequences wrt deleting `python36._pth`?  Just did this, and it worked like a charm... but feels too good to be true.

Comment: "._pth" is related to run the installation in a confined environment. deleting it frees, but still, there are problems of course, because we have only ".pyc" files for libraries, not the sources. there won't be code completion, for example, in IDEs because of this. @RTbecard

Comment: you should leave "import site" uncommented after installing pip, it will let "\lib\site-packages" in sys.path @rnso

Comment: @RTbecard deleting `python36._pth` turns the embedded version back to a normal version and it'll run off your local environment variables.

Answer (score 21):

how I installed pip into an embeddable python distribution:

1. unpack the python embeddable distro archive and cd there
2. run `python ./get-pip.py` (got [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py))
3. **EITHER** just uncomment string `import site` inside file pythonXX._pth **OR**
   copy folders (at least pip) from the newly-created folder Lib/site-packages/ into pythonXX.zip

now it's possible to `python -m pip ...`

Comment: With python38-64 on Win: pip can't install any packages. ErrMsg: `import distlib
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distlib'`. `distlib` can be another package.

Comment: Works flawlessly with Python 3.10 win64.

Comment: Notice to make sure site-packages are picked up, one needs to run `import sys; import os; sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.executable, 'Lib', 'site-packages'))` when starting python.
As to how to affect it BEFORE starting Python, see issue here: https://bugs.python.org/issue28245 Basically, modify python3xx._pth file. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50829079/2856597

Answer (score 9):

Solution for me was deleting this file:

```
python39._pth
```

This allows Pip to work, and also allow `import` from same directory.
Alternatively you can get this:

https://nuget.org/packages/python

Click "Download package", and you can extract just like a Zip file.

Comment: This works nicely! Maybe this should be the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: This just turns your embedded version into a normal version that reads your local environment variables and registry: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4207#issuecomment-297399016

Answer (score 1):

Get the PIP Standalone zip application from here: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/pip.pyz

Put it anywhere on your device. I prefer to put it on one folder level above Python.exe

Then install any package with:
.\python.exe .\pip.pyz install

The above method means that there is no need to download PIP, works great if you are leveraging Embedded python too.
This also makes it so much more secure as you are solely installing selected packages.

Source:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Answer (score 0):

It may be considered "cheating" but I installed pycharm. It asked for the python executable, but then was able to provide pip and the packages through pip.
You may need to play around a bit with pycharm, in order to create an environment around your python executable, especially if you have never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

To use python embedded on winb 10 and 11 you need :

1 Download on https://www.python.org/downloads/release

2 Unzip downloaded files

3 Add Unziped python directory on path

4 In the file python39._pth uncomment import site

5 Download get-python.py script on https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

6 Run python get-python.py on power shell or terminal

7 Open python directory and add Script directory on path

Answer (score -1):

Pip can also be accessed programatically within python as a command (this example installs pandas):

```
import pip
pip.main(['install'], 'pandas')
```

(Source: [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code))

Comment: I tried this approach. However it spawned a subprocess calling python, and because setuptools was not on the python path, it failed. So probably better to do one of the other approaches

Answer (score -1):

download https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/python-3.10.1-amd64.exe
and install it to a Virtual box

download https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.1/python-3.10.1-embed-amd64.zip
and unpack it to python-3.10.1-embed-amd64

copy "include" & "libs" dirs from corresponding python installation "python-3.10.1-amd64.exe" from Virtual Box to python-3.10.1-embed-amd64

goto python-3.10.1-embed-amd64 folder and:

- Download get-pip.py:

```bash
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

- Execute get-pip.py:

```bash
python get-pip.py
```

- rename _pth:

```bash
rename python310._pth python310._pth.renamed
```

set environments:

```bash
set PY_PIP=python-3.10.1-embed-amd64\Scripts
set PY_LIBS=python-3.10.1-embed-amd64\Lib;python-3.10.1-embed-amd64\Lib\site-packages
```

now "python -m pip install PACKETNAME" should work.
PACKETNAME is tested on:

- pywin32==302
- psutil==5.8.0
- pprofile==2.1.0
- mypy==0.910
- Pillow==8.4.0
- cfractions==1.4.0
- pyyaml==6.0
- humanize==3.13.1

Note: packets installs that require to compile C/C++ are also work.

Note: 'python-3.10.1-embed-amd64' means something like c:\mypythons\python-3.10.1-embed-amd64

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and after trying multiple approaches from the existing answers, this simple solution helped me!

#My case:
I installed python using embedded zip file. Set the env variables for python
Now I had to install pip. So i followed cli installation

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

which created the Scripts and Lib folder under my python folder.But  still i was getting, "pip is not recognized" message on cli.

#How I resolved it:

1. Go to the python folder and in the root, you ll find a ._pth file. Open it with editor and add this line at the bottom

> Lib\site-packages

So your file will look like this:

```
python312.zip
.

# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
Lib\site-packages
```

Now save it and in your cmd, you can run pip commands, it will be successful!

Comment: This answer does not seem to have any new info compared to this already existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48906746